# Android activity with no title bar crashes?

Tags: android

When I use this code to make my activity with no title my app crashes, I have tried it using .xml or by coding

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}
```

I also tried:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

MinSDK=14
TargetSDK:21

Any idea?

Comment: where is your logcat???

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

did the trick